# Adjacency matrix of triangular lattice in matlab

Tags: matlab, lattice, triangulation

I'm trying to triangulate a torus in Matlab - see the figure attached for a triangulation with N=9 vertices - but am having issues defining a function to dynamically construct an adjacency matrix for any N vertices. I haven't been able to find any similar answers on SE for constructing an adjacency matrix of a torus triangulation in Matlab, so would appreciate any input.

The background is that I'm looking at network properties on different graph topologies, and want to investigate such on a triangular lattice with 'periodic' boundary conditions (i.e. a torus triangulation).

[Triangulation of Torus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw3Mv.png)

Edit: here's the current matlab code, which isn't returning the expected adjacency matrix.

```matlab
N = 3;

A = zeros(N^2);
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:N
        if i == 1 && j == 1 % corner point
            A(i,2) = 1; A(i,1+N) = 1;
            A(i,N) = 1; A(i,2*N) = 1;
            A(i,1+N*(N-1)) = 1; A(i,2+N*(N-1)) = 1; 
            % reflect on diagonal: make symmetric
            A = triu(A) + triu(A)'; 
        else
            if i==1 % wrap around horizontal
                A(j,j+N*(N-1)) = 1;
                if j~=N % horiz+diagonal
                    A(j,j+1) = 1;
                    A(j,j+N*(N-1)+1) = 1;
                else % last diagonal
                    A(j,N*(N-1)+1) = 1;
                end
            end
            if j==1 % wrap around vertical
                A((i-1)*N+1,i*N) = 1;
                if i~=N
                   A((i-1)*N+1,(i)*N) = 1; % vertical
                   A((i-1)*N+1,(i+1)*N) = 1; % diagonal
                end
            end
        end

        if i ~= 1 && j ~= 1 && ...
           i ~= N && j ~= N % interior points (look at edges at higher node indices) 

            A((N-1)*i+j,(N-1)*i+j+1) = 1; % horiz
            A((N-1)*i+j,(N-1)*i+j+N-1) = 1; % diag down
            A((N-1)*i+j,(N-1)*i+j+N) = 1; % vert
        end

    end
end
A = triu(A) + triu(A)'; % reflect to make symmetric
```

Comment: This just looks like a normal problem that you have not tried to solve. Solving this has no much more mystery than sitting down and thinking a bit hard for a bit. Right now this looks like a code request because you decided not to do the thinking. Of course, I may be wrong!, but if I am, do edit the post and prove me wrong please

Comment: @AnderBiguri please see the edit above. I'm of course not requesting code, but would appreciate your input, or any links/resources you think I'd find relevant to the problem